# Using an array with sorting to collect a series of virtual "Cards" into alphabetical and numerical order.

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a method that is part of a larger program that I am writing as part of an assignment which is supposed to print out an array of virtual "cards" that are defined in another class, and then print it out again, sorting the cards by their suit(C, D, H, J).  For each suit, the cards must be sorted by their kind(1-13).  So, the end result should look something like this:

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 D1 D2 D3....ect.

Right now, my output looks like this.  It's close, but all I've managed to do is reverse the third line of output.  The first three lines are correct:

> 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 8 8 8 10 10 10 11 15 16 17 18 18 20 21 23 24 25 25 26 27 28 29 
>   [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,8,8,10,10,10,11,15,16,17,18,18,20,21,23,24,25,25,26,27,28,29]
>
> [D11 , C3 , C10 , D1 , H13 , C12 , H4 , H11 , C13 , C7 , D4 , C6 , S10 , D8 , H1 , H5 , H10 , D6 , D5 , S9 , C9 , C5 , H9 , S7 , S6 , H6 , D3 , S12 , D12 , C1 , D10 , H2 , H8 , C4 , H7 , D2 , D7 , H3 , S2 , C2 , D13 , S1 , S3 , S11 , H12 , C8 , C11 , S13 , D9 , S4 , S8 , S5 ]

[S5 ,S8 ,S4 ,D9 ,S13 ,C11 ,C8 ,H12 ,S11 ,S3 ,S1 ,D13 ,C2 ,S2 ,H3 ,D7 ,D2 ,H7 ,C4 ,H8 ,H2 ,D10 ,C1 ,D12 ,S12 ,D3 ,H6 ,S6 ,S7 ,H9 ,C5 ,C9 ,S9 ,D5 ,D6 ,H10 ,H5 ,H1 ,D8 ,S10 ,C6 ,D4 ,C7 ,C13 ,H11 ,H4 ,C12 ,H13 ,D1 ,C10 ,C3 ,D11 ]

What would be the best way to do this?  There are two parts of my code that I suspect are the problem.  I've attached the two parts of my program below.  There is a third part that defines the cards, but it does not need changes.

SortedArray Class(creates the cards that are used in the "deck", which is an array.  Also provides methods for the manipulation of the arrays).

```
public class SortedArray<XCard extends java.lang.Comparable<XCard>>
implements java.lang.Iterable<XCard>{

    private int size; 
    private XCard[] data;

    //creates an array of Comparable object with size = 10
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SortedArray(){
        data = (XCard[]) new Comparable [10]; 
        size = 0;   


    }

    //capacity constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SortedArray(int capacity){
        data = (XCard[]) new Comparable [capacity];
                this.size = capacity;

    }


    //Copy constructor
    public SortedArray(SortedArray<XCard> a){
        //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        data = (XCard[]) new Comparable[a.data.length];
        this.size = a.size;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                data[i] = a.data[i];
            }

    }

    private int notLess(XCard item){

        int i = 0;
        while (i < size && ((Comparable<XCard>) data[i]).compareTo(item) < 0){          //<
                i++;
            }


        return i;

    }

    public int indexOf(XCard item){

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(data[i].equals(item)){
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;

    }

    public XCard get(int i ){       

        if(i < 0 || i >= size)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(i);
            return data[i];
        }


    public XCard set(int i, XCard item){
        if(i < 0 || i>= size){
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(i);
        }
        XCard old = data[i];
        data[i] = item;
        return old;
    }

    private void doubleCapacity(){

        int cp = data.length * 2;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    XCard[] newList = (XCard[]) new Comparable[cp];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            newList[i] = data[i];

        }
            data = newList;
    }

    public void add(XCard item){
        add(notLess(item),item);    

    }



    public void add(int i, XCard item){

        if (i < 0 || i > size )
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.valueOf(i)); 

        if(size == data.length)
            doubleCapacity();
        for(int k = size; k > i; k--){ //>
            data[k] = data [k-1];
            }
        size ++;
        data[i] = item;

    }


    public int size(){
        return size; 

    }

    public XCard remove(int i){
        if(i < 0 || i > size){
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(i);
        }
        XCard item = data[i];
        for(int k = i; k < size - i; k++){
            data[k] = data[k+1];
            size--;

        }
        return item;
    }

    public Comparable[] toArray(){

        Comparable[] newArray = new Comparable [size];
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    newArray[i] = data[i];

                }

            return newArray;

        }


    public String toString(){

        String str = "[";
        str = str + data[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++){
            if(data[i] != null){
                str = str + "," + data[i];
                }
            }
            str = str + "]";


            return str;
        }

    //constructor for inner class   
    public Iterator<XCard> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<XCard>{ //inner class

          int num1, num2;

      //iterator constructor
      public MyIterator(){
         num1 = 0;
         num2 = -1; //-1
    }

      @Override
          public boolean hasNext() {
              return num1 >= size; //< 
          }

          @Override
          public XCard next() {
              num2 = num1;
            return data[num1++];

          }

          @Override
          public void remove() {
              if(num2 <= -1){
                throw new IllegalStateException("");
              }
              SortedArray.this.remove(num1);
              num1 = 0;
              num2 = -1;

          }

    }
```

}

Main Method:

`public class testClass {

```
public static void testInteger() {
    SortedArray<Integer> x = new SortedArray<Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        x.add((Integer) (int) (Math.random()*30.0));
    }

    Object[] b = x.toArray();
    for (int i=0; i< b.length; i++)
        System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
    System.out.println();   

    System.out.println(x.toString());
    Iterator<Integer> ix = x.iterator();
    while (ix.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(ix.next());
    }   
}

static void print(Card[] a) {
    for (int i=0; i< a.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i].toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void testXCard() {
    PokerDeck deck = new PokerDeck();
    deck.shuffle();
    ArrayList<Card> a = deck.toArrayList();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    Iterator<Card> ia = a.iterator();
    SortedArray<XCard> x = new SortedArray<XCard>();
    while (ia.hasNext()) {
        Card temp = ia.next();
        System.out.println(temp.toString());
        x.add(new XCard(temp.getSuit(),temp.getKind()));
    }
    System.out.println(x.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testInteger();
    testXCard();
}
```

}

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why create SortedArray at all?, Why not just sort the deck of cards using Collections.sort(pass in your comparator class here)

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing a program about SortedArrays, you're writing a program about Cards.  Each card has two attributes: suit and rank.

See where I'm going with this?

Your class SortedArray is written largely procedurally rather than using an object-oriented view.  The object in which you are interested is Card.  What you really ought to do is define a class "Card" with two fields, Rank and Suit (which should contain references to enum constants).

```
class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    private final m_suit;
    private final m_rank;

    Card(Suit s, Rank r) { m_suit = s;  m_rank = r; }
    :
    :
}
```

Your compareTo method should first examine m_suit, and then if those are equal then compare m_rank.  This will generate the natural order you desire.  A `List<Card>` instance defined this way could be simply sorted by using Arrays.sort().